# Calculate standard deviation in Matlab

Tags: matlab, standard-deviation

I have a pre-allocate array with size 100:

```
a = zeros(1, 100);
% Do some thing....
% Calculate standard deviation here.
```

Now I want to calculate standard deviation from element 1 to element 20. How can I do that?

With function `std` , it just calculates the whole array.

Answer (score 6):

use `std(a(1:20))`

`a(1:20)` extracts the first 20 elements of vector `a`.